# How to normalize an uint16 image and convert it to uint8 when max pixel value is less than 65535?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, scikit-image, normalize

I need to convert an image from uint16 to uint8 in order to save it to disk when the max pixel value of the uint16 image is not 65535(it is less than that value)(it is 2970, in fact). I have noticed that scikit-image has the method **img_as_ubyte** for such conversion. It seems this method converts 65535 into 255 and all values in proportion to that. Problem is that image has a maximum value of 2000 which is converted to 12 and a lot of resolution is lost. Also I am considering to save the image as a numpy

I tried using the rescale function proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57419882) and also the cv2.normalize function. However, I noticed that cv2.normalize function creates an image of **dtype=uint16**.

Also, I checked with mat2gray from matlab and cv2.normalize was more similar to mat2gray than the method with normalize function in plain python.

**Using plain python:**

```
orig_min = mammogram_dicom.min()
orig_max = mammogram_dicom.max()
target_min = 0.0
target_max = 255.0
mammogram_scaled = (mammogram_dicom-orig_min)*((target_max- 
target_min)/(orig_max-orig_min))+target_min
mammogram_uint8_by_function = mammogram_scaled.astype(np.uint8)
```

I feel it strange to use the np.uint8 I would rather not use it but it is the only way I got to go to uint 8

**For cv2.normalized I also had to use np.uint8 to get uint8:**

```
mammogram_uint8_by_cv2 = np.zeros(mammogram_dicom.shape).astype(np.uint8)
mammogram_uint8_by_cv2 = cv2.normalize(mammogram_dicom, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
```

Is there a better way to convert uint16 in uint8 this image?

I am expecting a similar or better behavior to mat2gray in matlab. I made a comparison between the same image from matlab and one calculated with above code. Cv2 normalize is the one most similar. The method with the rescale function -which I called plain python- looks similar to the naked eye, but making the difference:
    mat2gray_from_matlab_image - plain_python_image

has some diferences with a value of 1 pixel

Is there a way to normalize the image inside scikit-image?

Answer (score 6):

### 1) OpenCV solution

OpenCV [`normalize`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) returns an image of the same type as the source if `dtpye` is not specified. To normalize a `uint16` to `uint8` without numpy use:

```
mammogram_uint8_by_cv2 = cv2.normalize(mammogram_dicom, None, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX, dtype=cv2.CV_8U)
```

### 2) Skimage solution

First [`rescale`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.exposure.html?highlight=exposure#skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity) the image to the full range and the convert it to `uint8` using [`img_as_ubyte`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.html#skimage.img_as_ubyte) :

```
from skimage import exposure, img_as_ubyte
mammogram_uint8_by_ski = img_as_ubyte(exposure.rescale_intensity(mammogram_dicom))
```

Comment: @LeninGF Please see my updated answer for a purley `skimage` solution without `OpenCV`

Comment: @LeninGF Did this answer solve your issue? If so please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer. If not please comment. This keeps this site useful and helps others easyly find a solution for similar problems. Thanks.